# Can one prevent stack overflow by storing strings in memory backwards?

Tags: memory, stack-overflow

Normal use:

```
  ------(buffer)------  --(ret)---
  DDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEE  EEEE  FFFF
  89ABCDEF0123456789AB  CDEF  0123
  this is a string\0    bff5  a400
```

Stack overflowed:

```
  ------(buffer)------  --(ret)---
  DDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEE  EEEE  FFFF 
  89ABCDEF0123456789AB  CDEF  0123
  oh no you got hacked  cadf  aff0 \0
```

Could you prevent this by putting the initial value of the string in the last (or, if there are other variables, closest to last) memory slot (EB) and making each subsequent letter each previous slot? E.g.

```
  ------(buffer)------  --(ret)---
  DDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEE  EEEE  FFFF 
  89ABCDEF0123456789AB  CDEF  0123
  dekcah tog uoy on ho  bff5  a400 (no harm to ret pointer)
```

I understand there are better and more widely-accepted stack overflow preempts (canaries, noexec, ASLR). I'm just wondering. Would this fix the problem? Would it be technically feasible?

Comment: By the way, there are exploitable memory conditions other than stack overflow - heap overflow, use after free, and more. Canaries only prevent stack overflows, and do it quite well. Noexec and ASLR help prevent all kinds of memory exploits - but unfortunately they are not as reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code doesn't protect from writing into adjacent memory spaces, then no you can't reverse the order and be protected from a buffer overflow. Reversing the way the string is stored just changes the shellcode payload arrangement (i.e. the payload may come first and the NOPS [`x\00`] may go in last). Like this:

> x\DEx\ADx\BEx\EF\x00x\00x\00

**vs**

> x\00x\00x\00x\DEx\ADx\BEx\EF

*As you mentioned, there are much better coding practices that protect against buffer overflows.*

Comment: I mean that you *can* write into adjacent memory, but each subsequent character of a string is in the memory slot before, so that the string progresses away from the ret pointer, not towards it.

Comment: That's not how the stack works. Stacks grow *toward* low memory addresses (vs heaps, which grow toward high-numbered memory), thus once you corrupt the stack (i.e. gain control of the instruction pointer) you can **overflow** into where you want to be (*insert beginning of payload here*). Read: Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit for an awesome primer!

Answer (score 0):

It would probably stop some attacks that rely on exploiting `strcpy` and the like (when copying stuff around on the stack) because if you write into the opposite direction of the return address on the stack you at least can't overwrite that directly. It would still allow you to overwrite other things on the stack - possibly pointers - among many other things. It also wont protect against `memcpy` and many other things. Stack cannaries work pretty much against every buffer overflow. Stack cannaries however do not prevent an attacker from overwriting other pointers on the stack. Meaning you can still control pointers on the stack and use these pointers and other things in the code to write to arbitrary memory locations including the return address on the stack.